# How to send a XML request with httpclient and receive a file? (Java)

Tags: web-services, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

I need to send a XML request to a webservice which was not developed using SOAP protocoal. The webservice only works with pure XML request/answer, so there is not WSDL. The webservice will answer with a gzip file which I have to download. Can anyone help me please? I started with the code below. Thanks!

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean success = XMLDataPost();
    System.out.println(success);
}

private static boolean  XMLDataPost(){

    boolean success = false;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://webservice.blablabla.com.br");

        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("<RequestVeiculo><login>02566288000191</login><senha>159828</senha></RequestVeiculo>");
        reqEntity.setContentType("text/xml");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true);

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            success = true;
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Tamanho: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
            System.out.println("Chunked?: " + resEntity.isChunked());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return success;
}
}
```

Comment: How does it work so far? Are you getting the 200 status code? Are you getting anything in the resEntity?